# How to enable http2 in Windows 10 Server Technical preview

Tags: internet-explorer, http, iis, windows-10, http2

I've just downloaded and installed the VHD of "Windows 10 Server Technical Preview 2 Build 10074"

I've followed the instructions:
http://blogs.iis.net/nazim/http-2-for-iis-in-windows-10-technical-preview

..to create a selfsigned certificate, and I'm browsing localhost via IE11 and I don't get any http2 indication in F12 developer tools, like the link implies.  Browsing using another machine and chrome with the http2/spdy [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http2-and-spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin) also doesn't indicate http2 traffic.

Am I missing a configuration step?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was using Windows Server 2016 TP2 to test the same thing and after enabling http/2 in the registry the local IE11 browser does not show any indication of http/2. The last screenshot of the [article you mentioned](http://blogs.iis.net/nazim/http-2-for-iis-in-windows-10-technical-preview) shows `http2`, so we assume it doesn't work.

Looking at the network tools in Chrome on a workstation also doesn't indicate http/2.

However when using Chrome 43 and typing:

> chrome://net-internals/#spdy

and then opening the test site in another tab, it will show up in the `HTTP/2 sessions` list with a `Protocol Negotiated: h2`

So my assumption here is, that IIS works fine serving http/2 but IE doesn't tell us about it.

Which begs the question: `Why does is show in the screenshot in the blog post?`

I can't answer that, but I'm satisfied with what I see in Chrome.

Edit 17-July-2015:

While doing some more tests for my blog post [New features in IIS 10](http://peter.hahndorf.eu/blog/iis10) I looked into this again and I now don't think you have to do anything in IIS 10 to enable HTTP/2. It seems to be enabled by default.